# Button in bootstrap form doesn't submit text from imput

Tags: django, forms

I'm exercising an easy project in Django.

I have a problem with the bootstrap button. The button generally works, because it gets over csrf_token to my home view in the request object but it doesn't submit data from my input, and here is my question. Why?

**My form:**

```
<form class="d-flex" action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="your new task" aria-label="Search">
        <button  value="Send" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"  name="no_dalej">Add to list</button>
      </form>
```

**The request object looks like this:**

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['fJNmnuulcaNB7SETFNagSFfsfiynOCwyw0LMoALPSlEcYFnxqIFMxPm7VliUylwm'], 'no_dalej': ['']}>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to provide a name attribute to the search input

```
<form class="d-flex" action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<input class="form-control me-2" type="search" name="q" placeholder="your new task" aria-label="Search">
<button  value="Send" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"  name="no_dalej">Add to list</button>
</form>
```

Then in your view you grab the variable from the request

if its a GET request

```
 query = request.GET.get('q')
```

if its a POST request

```
query = request.POST.get('q')
```